# Writing Robust Application Layer Message Parser

Tags: networking, serialization, tcp, network-programming

There is an application that uses TCP/IP suite in communication. I am writing a message parser in application layer. It can fetch TCP byte stream and deserialize bytes, according to predetermined message structure. If, however, the incoming byte stream is wrong, the parser gets confused. Then, every consecutive stream is interpreted wrongly in parser. My question is "Are there any methods to spot contradictory stream and discard it so that next streams can be interpreted correctly"?

note: If this is too broad, please request details.

Comment: I removed C++ tag, do you have any recommendation of tags?

Comment: TCP is not a message protocol, and it may combine or segment application messages, so you would need to build an application-layer protocol to do messages correctly. That is why we have things like HTTP on top of TCP. Otherwise, you could use UDP for messages.

Comment: I already mentioned that the parser is in application layer?

Comment: Then you need to give us code to see what you are doing wrong.